# Find all unused static variables from a file

Tags: java, eclipse, static

My eclipse has 6 projects which are interdependent on each other(2 become jars other 4 are wars) actually its a jboss project where i have 4 portlets, now i want to detect all the stativ variables in a class(its basically a constants file) which are not used by any of the other ptoject

Is there any tool available in eclipse which can help me in achieving the same?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find all unused variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356345/find-all-unused-variable)

Comment: @TedHopp - that question is for netbeans, i want something for eclipse

Comment: [findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) and [ucdetector](http://www.ucdetector.org/). don't know if they'll function across war files though...

Comment: @Varun - I think Ted is implying that you should bite the bullet and use NetBeans for this task.

Comment: @All - thats why opened a question it has some other requirements then the question being mentioned its interproject check not inside a single project

Comment: Findbugs (the top-voted answer in that thread) also runs under Eclipse.

Comment: @StephenC - so i should use netbeans just to check whether i am using static variables of a class? and ask my other teammates also to move to netbeans ? i guess not a good suggestion

Comment: @TedHopp - does it work between projects? i guess its used to check with in the same project

Comment: Findbugs can work on a .war file in Eclipse. See [the manual](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/eclipse.html#d0e1691)

Comment: "its basically a constants file" - how many constants are there?

Comment: @Asaf - around 100 can be more...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: [Lean on the compiler](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/software-engineering-and-development/0131177052/how-do-i-know-that-i-m-not-breaking-anything/ch23lev1sec4)
Assuming you have reasonable number of Constants in that file, Comment them, and fix all the compilation errors un-commenting the used ones.
*This may be a better use of your time*

Option 2: [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) for [Eclipse](http://pmd-eclipse.sourceforge.net/).
Haven't tried it myself for that particular purpose thou.

Comment: liked the option 1 though a lengthy process

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the static variable.  You have 2 choices. Open call hierarchy or references --> workspace

Comment: That's good for testing variables one at a time. I imagine that OP wants a tool that tests them all automatically and reports the results.

Comment: @TedHopp - yup i want the same